# SQL - get version when 1 or more

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 db Tables - Article and Article_Version.

Article Table:

```
=====ID====|======Date_Added=====|==================Link===================
      1           01/01/2018          www.guardian.co.uk/sports/abc.html
      2           07/01/2018          www.guardian.co.uk/sports/def.html
      3           02/01/2018          www.guardian.co.uk/sports/abc.html
```

ArticleVersion:

```
=====Id=====|=====DateAdded=====|=====ArticleId=====|=====Version=====
     1             01/01/2018             1                1
     2             07/01/2018             2                1
     3             02/01/2018             3                2
```

Now I am trying to construct a query where I can get a list of all articleversions for any article that has more than 1 version. My C# code hashes values to know if version number increased.

I need help writing a query to return  list of all articleversions for any article that has more than 1 version.

I have this but it doesn't return the right results

```
SELECT ArticleVersion.*,Article.link 
FROM ArticleVersion
JOIN Article ON Article.Id=ArticleVersion.ArticleId
WHERE VERSION > 1;
```

Please can someone help where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this.

```
SELECT AV.*, A.link 
FROM ArticleVersion AV
JOIN Article A ON A.Id=AV.ArticleId
WHERE 
    EXISTS( SELECT * FROM ArticleVersion AV2 
        WHERE AV2.ArticleId = AV.ArticleId
            AND AV2.Id <> AV.Id )
```

Comment: Thank you sir @Serkan Arslan... This solves my problem

Answer (score 0):

You want all versions.  A window function comes to mind:

```
SELECT av.*, a.link 
FROM Article a JOIN
     (SELECT av.*, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY av.ArticleId) as cnt
      FROM ArticleVersion av
     ) av
     ON a.Id = av.ArticleId
WHERE cnt > 1;
```

Your version of the query misses the first version due to the filtering.

Comment: Thanks.. what do i need to change to get original version too?.. Appreciate the help

Comment: @Jane_ami . . . That's the point of this answer.  It gets the original version too.